# Using grep to search for a word in a very long string

Tags: linux, bash, text, grep, bigdata

I have a huge file containing a unique long string. I need to search for a specific word in that file. Of course I cannot use `gedit` or similar software because they chock. So, a solution could be `grep`. The problem is that it returns the full string into the shell if the word matches, so I cannot find where the word is located and I cannot observe the other near words.

Is there any particular option to pass in order to stop/pause the grep shell stream (e.g., a certain number of chars after the match) as soon as it finds my word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-o` option to "Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN."

Example:

```
% cat lorem
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                                                                                                                                              
% grep -oE '.{20}fugiat.{20}' lorem
se cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Exc
```

Edit: @tripleee suggested the E part, to give padding on either side of the match.

Comment: I also need to see near words to my match, e.g., ``...esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur...``

Comment: Then try `grep -oE '.{40}word.{40}' file` to obtain 40 characters of context on either side of the match. GNU `grep` also has `--color` to highlight the match.

Comment: Notice that `-E` changes to a different regex syntax. The beef here is the `.{40}` which would be `........................................` in traditional `grep`; but modern `grep` supports the same construct, only you need fugly backslashes; `.\{40\}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`-m NUM, --max-count=NUM`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) option:

```
$ grep -m 1 [pattern] [/path/to/file]
```

> Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines. If the input is standard input from a regular file, and NUM matching lines are output, grep ensures that the standard input is positioned to just after the last matching line before exiting, regardless of the presence of trailing context lines. This enables a calling process to resume a search. When grep stops after NUM matching lines, it outputs any trailing context lines. When the -c or --count option is also used, grep does not output a count greater than NUM. When the -v or --invert-match option is also used, grep stops after outputting NUM non-matching lines.

Comment: This still shows my full line when there is a match.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question! I thought you were more concerned with stopping after the first match not stopping directly after a match.